# Control AC Sync. Motor by Blocking AC Cycles

Tags: motor, ac, motor-controller, synchronous-motor

I have an AC synchronous centrifugal water pump that I would like to control the speed of.  The main goal is to slowly start the pump and ramp up to full speed over about 60 seconds.  I believe this can usually be accomplished by a Variable Frequency Drive device but those usually do a lot more and cost too much to make this worthwhile.

Instead of converting the wall AC power to DC and then back to AC at various frequencies I was wondering if it would be possible to simple remove certain cycles from the 60hz AC power to get a lower frequency.  For example if I wanted to start the pump at quarter speed I would remove 3 out of every 4 AC cycles.  This would result in 15hz although it would also result in a pause between each hertz.  This kind of solution would be fairly easy to make with an Arduino and a dimmer board but I was wondering if anyone has any feedback on this.  Would this even work or would an AC synchronous motor not like the pauses between the cycles?

Comment: My gut feeling is that this would destroy the motor, if you even managed to do that; any motor will generate a large voltage spike if you try to cut its voltage off. Motors are basically inductors, after all!

Comment: 'Synchronous' motors will make loud noises, if not smoke, with such erratic drive.   A different motor type (universal, or DC motor) might suit your needs.

Comment: What you are describing is called a cycloconverter. Cycloconverters have had some use, but the designs have been a little more complex than the one you have described. Synchronous motors are usually either very small - a few watts to a few hundred watts, or very large - a few megawatts or larger. Are you sure that you have a synchronous motor? Is it single-phase or three-phase? Is is a permanent magnet motor or a wound field motor? What voltage is it designed for?

Comment: I doubt it is a synchronous motor.  More likely an asynchronous single-phase motor.  Irregardless, they don't like missing portions of the wave, as in 1 in 4.  It may start but may let the magic smoke out under load.

Comment: I double checked and it is indeed a shaded pole synchronous motor with a magnetic rotor.  It's about 30W and designed for single phase 120V.